# WebBrowser Control

Tags: c#-2.0

Please help me.

```
<div id="id1">$97</div>
```

sometimes, id1 innerHTML value is changes.

My problems is:

If this values is change, i want to do somethings. How i can know this value is changes. I using webbrowser control and c#.

Comment: Can you elaborate more? Is it a winform or webform app?

Comment: It is winform. Often, id1 innerHTML value(price) is changes. If price is chage i want to show message box.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have access to a Vb.NET converter but this "may" work I haven't tested it....I would get the element by it's id which is id1 and then get the id1 and save it to a text file or a database, etc.

Next you would recall id again to compare it against the previous inner text. If the number has changed then the app is to messagebox you the change if not...nothing happens or you could code a message box to say something to that effect.

But either way here is the code that I could think of under a button..

```
Dim count As Integer = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("id1").InnerText
'Here is where you would call the old value maybe run this through a loop and save the value to a text file...then pull it back up when you need to check it to compare it to the current value being shown.    

If count <> count Then
MessageBox.Show("count")
End If
```